# Android - how to verify an in-app purchase?

Tags: android

I'm trying learn about in-app purchases by following this tutorial http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

here's my code so far:

```
public class main extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("BillingService", "Starting");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startService(new Intent(this, BillingService.class));
        BillingHelper.setCompletedHandler(mTransactionHandler);

    }

    ////////////////////////////////

    public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

                Log.e("IN APP", "Transaction complete");
                Log.e("IN APP", "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
                Log.e("IN APP", "Item purchased is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);

                if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased())
                {
                    showItem();
                }

            };

    };

    ////////////////////////////////

    public void BuyButtonClick(View v) {

        if(BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()){
            Log.e("IN APP","Trying to buy...");
            BillingHelper.requestPurchase(this, "android.test.purchased"); 
        } else {
            Log.e("IN APP","Can't purchase on this device");
        }

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void showItem() {

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText("PAID!");

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        BillingHelper.stopService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////

}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I also want some way to check if the item was purchased when the app starts. I assume it might use **BillingHelper.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature)** , but what data and sig should I put in there? Or maybe there's some other way about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check when the application starts by using **restoreTransactions**. If you have used Managed Products or Subscriptions then only you will get all the details of the user.

For Unmanaged product there is no detail maintained by google.

So call this in your main activity

```
mBillingService = new BillingService();
mBillingService.setContext(this);
mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
```

Once you call this in ResponseHandler class there is one method **purchaseResponse**

```
purchaseResponse(final Context context,
        final PurchaseState purchaseState, final String productId,
        final String orderId, final long purchaseTime,
        final String developerPayload, final String purchaseToken) {
 }
```

which will return all the details.

You can check purchaseState then after

```
           if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {

            } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.REFUNDED) {

            } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.CANCELED) {

            }
```